# Creating a CSV with ConvertToDateTme variables

Tags: powershell, csv

I can create a CSV from the following code, however it fails to give details on the "System Up Time" for days.

It displays the hours and the minutes no problem, but instead of giving a number before days, just prints out the word days.

```
Server  Last Rebooted     System Up Time
Srv1    25/07/2018 20:49  Days 12 Hours 37 Minutes
PC1     04/02/2019 15:55  Days 17 Hours 31 Minutes
```

I have tried to surround the `$Uptime` variable with parentheses, but to no avail. I have also tried `$_.Days` to get the information without any luck.

```
$Path = "C:\Temp\Manual_Servers"
$Tx = "\Servers.txt"
$CS = "\Res.csv"
$File = $Path + $tx
$Server = GC $File
$Np = "\Res.txt"
$Res = $Path + $Np
$Res2 = $Path + $CS

function Uptime2 {
    $Server | ForEach-Object {
        $SF = $_
        $os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $uptime = (Get-Date) - $os.ConvertToDateTime($os.LastBootUpTime)
        $OS |
            Select-Object @{Name="Server";Expression={$SF}},
                @{Name="Last Rebooted";Expression={($_.ConvertToDateTime($os.LastBootUpTime)).DateTime}},
                @{Name="System Up Time";Expression={$_.$uptime.Days + "Days " + $uptime.Hours + " Hours " + $uptime.Minutes + " Minutes" }} |
           Export-Csv $Res2 -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
}
Uptime2
```

Desired result:

```
Server  Last Rebooted     System Up Time
Srv1    25/07/2018 20:49  200 Days 12 Hours 37 Minutes
PC1     04/02/2019 15:55  9 Days 17 Hours 31 Minutes
```

Comment: Try the following CIMInstance as it outputs directly to DateTime so you wont need to do any conversion:


    (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootupTime


you could then create variables for months,days,minutes etc and use the above appended with .Day, .Minute etc

Comment: Thanks for that, but I would I employ it in getting the details for remote machines?

Comment: `$_.$uptime.Days` -> `$uptime.Days`

Comment: Yeah I thought that, however it displays nothing. in the column a little confused as to why this would be happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code as a base example and reworking it to your needs:

```
    $servers = 'COREDC01','COREDC02'
    $currentDT = Get-Date

    foreach ($i in $servers) {
        $BootTime = (Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $i -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootupTime
        $uptime = $currentDT - $BootTime

        Write-Output `
            -InputObject "Uptime for Server $i -
            Days:$($uptime.Days),
            Hours:$($uptime.Hours),
            Minutes:$($uptime.Minutes),
            Seconds:$($uptime.Seconds)
        "
    }
```

Comment: Again, same result, even with code suggested, it seems its not seeing the days value, picks up everything else fine.

Comment: well thats weird because my code works for me:


PS C:\Windows\system32> . 'C:\Temp\Untitled2.ps1' <# script is not saved yet #>
Uptime for Server COREDC01 -
        Days:0,
        Hours:0,
        Minutes:14,
        Seconds:49
    
Uptime for Server COREDC02 -
        Days:0,
        Hours:0,
        Minutes:15,
        Seconds:0

Comment: are you checking across a mix of OS versions? just wondering now if its a PowerShell version issue and something is different between v2 and the newer versions.

Comment: Im running 5.1 ps, im using vscode to see the variables and it contains the days, but fails to print it into the spreadsheet. Im as confused as you are.

Comment: does my code above print it to the PS console correctly?
also can you try it in a new/clean session?

Comment: Bizzarely here is the solution;

        $Boot| Select-Object @{Name="Server";Expression={$SF}},
                   @{Name="Last Rebooted";Expression={$($boot)}},
                   @{Name="System Up Time";Expression= {$Boot.$uptime.Seconds +""+ $uptime.Days + " Days " + $uptime.Hours + " Hours " + $uptime.Minutes + " Minutes "}}| Export-CSv $Res2 -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Append

I Had to add the $uptime.seconds to print nothing then add a blank "" for it to print out correctly.

See results;

Answer (score 0):

Bizzarely here is the solution;

```
$Boot| Select-Object @{Name="Server";Expression={$SF}}, 
@{Name="Last  Rebooted";Expression={$($boot)}}, 
@{Name="System Up Time";Expression= {$Boot.$uptime.Seconds +""+ $uptime.Days + "  Days " + $uptime.Hours + " Hours " +  $uptime.Minutes + " Minutes "}}

| Export-CSv $Res2 -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

I Had to add the $uptime.seconds to print nothing then add a blank "" for it to print out correctly. See results;

[image]